# iCal feed import - Timezone query

Tags: plugin-development, datetime, import, timezone, feed

Has anyone got any experience working with iCal feeds - I have written a plugin utilising the [CalFileParser library](https://github.com/controlz/CalFileParser) but the UK clock changes have thrown all the items out, so eg an all day event is now showing up as at 11pm the day before. For example:

`BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20170418T230000Z
DTSTAMP:20170412T114209Z
DTSTART:20170418T230000Z
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:F4 Careers Day
UID:65d28288-9ba7-404c-85fe-b66682e2f605
END:VEVENT`

Is importing as 23:00 on 18/04/2017. However importing the feed into Calendar (Mac) is reporting the event as expected at 00:00 on 19/04/2017.

If I update my site settings to BST (UTC+1) and parse the value into a DateTime object then it outputs to screen correctly, eg:

`$tmp = DateTime::createFromString($item['dtstart']->date);`

Outputs:

`Craft\DateTime Object ( [date] => 2017-04-19 00:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/London )`

However, on saving to my database record (to a column with AttributeType::DateTime) this date value is saved as `2017-04-18 23:00:00`. This means that any attempt to retrieve and show this on my site outputs the wrong date/time.

Any thoughts on how to get my script to acknowledge the time difference and save this to the relevant record without having to tinker with the code every 6 months?

Cole

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like that CalFileParser library you are using has some issues with timezones. There is a pull-request that supposedly fixes these, but I would rather exchange it for another library.

https://github.com/u01jmg3/ics-parser has the more modern codebase, seems to be actively maintained, more used, and can be installed using composer.

Comment: Thanks @carlcs - indeed was a problem with the CalFileParser plugin. There was a [recent Pull Request](https://github.com/controlz/CalFileParser/pulls) that updating to resolved.

When time permits will try to move to a more recent codebase.